# Found how long user is on UIView for

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Can I find out how long a user is sat on a UIViewController for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set an NSDate in `-viewDidAppear:` and call `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:yourDate]` in `-viewDidDisappear:`. You'll get the number of seconds spent in the `UIViewController`.

If don't want you track time when the application is not active, add the `UIViewController` as an observer for the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification & UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, calling the `-didBecomeActive` and `-didResignActive` methods respectively.

```
- (void)didBecomeActive 
{
    self.startDate = [NSDate date];
}
- (void)didResignActive
{
    timeSpent += [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate]
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self didBecomeActive];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self didResignActive];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

**Update: added code to handle if app becomes inactive**

Comment: What about if a user backgrounds the app and then brings it forward again after a sustained period of time?

Comment: You could register the controller as an observer and add the time interval to an instance variable on UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, and reset the startDate on UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification.

Comment: It was more of a rhetorical question - why not update your answer for completeness?